# Foundation Menu Styling

Tags: css, menu, zurb-foundation

I am trying to get vertical bars into my menu and can't work it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/r46s08Lp/

Trying to use this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).foundation();
    
})
```

```css
.top-bar {
    background: #fff;
}

.top-bar-section ul li{
     background: #fff !important;
}

.top-bar-section li a:not(.button) {
    background: #fff !important;
    color: #4a4a4a !important;
    font-weight:bolder;    
}

.top-bar-section li a:not(.button):hover {
    background: #ebebeb !important;   
}

.top-bar-section ul li.active > a {
    background: #ebebeb !important;  
}

.top-bar-section ul li.active > a:hover {
    background: #ebebeb !important;   
}

.top-bar-section li:before {
content: " | ";
}

.top-bar-section li:first-child:before {
content: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar data-options="is_hover: false">
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
                <h1>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/ukih" target="_self">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/ukih/about" target="_self">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/ukih/projects" target="_self">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/ukih/investment" target="_self">Investments</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/ukih/contact" target="_self">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The whole menu shifts down when i do this.
I also tried to add it just before the a tag, that works maybe a little bit better, as it adds it in front of the menu item, but because it is inside the li tag i can't make it nicely centered in between the menu items. It just sort of sits in-front of each item.

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `border-left` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following CSS.

Basically:

```
border-right: 1px solid;
```

adds a "line" between items in your menu.

```
ul > li:last-child { border-right: 0;}
```

Remove the border on last item on the right side.

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/r46s08Lp/3/

```
.top-bar {
    background-color: white;

}

.top-bar-section li a:not(.button) {
    background: #fff !important;
    color: #4a4a4a !important;
    font-weight:bolder;    
}

ul > li {
    border-right: 1px solid;

}
ul > li:last-child {
    border-right: 0;

}
```

---

If necessary you can adjust the height for your "line" using the following CSS:

```
.top-bar-section li a:not(.button) {height: 50px;}
```